# How to get internet speed and CPU temperatures in java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, networking, sigar, oshi

I need to get the internet speed (upload and download per second) in java. I'm currently using the Sigar and Oshi libraries but none of them shows me the speed as I would like.

On the network I found [this](https://gist.github.com/nlinker/3775022) class using Sigar to see the connection speed but I find the values completely wrong.

With Oshi I can not find the speed per second.

Some help?

In intellij console the values are wrong compared with speedtest:
[image: In intellij console the values are wrong compared with speedtest]

Comment: There is a mismatch between what you're getting from Sigar (Interface total bytes) and what you're getting from speedtest (Megabits per second for this file transfer).  To get a similar "Maximum Bytes per second" sort of measurement, you'll have to start a timer, do something that uses up a lot of bandwidth, stop the timer... then decide how many bytes that was, and divide it by how long it took.

Comment: First of all thank you for correcting the post, my english is not so good

my program must monitor the speed on the Internet for any program (if I download something from chrome, I would like to show the current speed in my program).

Comment: Like in Windows task manager, in the performance tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the network stats

You need to divide the amount of bytes received on the time that has passed

You'll get better results from sleeping/waiting for a bit longer.
There's a few interesting facts of Java, one of them being that asking for a sleep time of Nms won't necessarily have the thread sleep for that amount of time (it's more along the line of asking the thread to "sleep as close to Nms as you are able").

The code should look more like:

```
long download1 = net.getBytesRecv();
long timestamp1 = net.getTimeStamp();
Thread.sleep(2000); //Sleep for a bit longer, 2s should cover almost every possible problem
net.updateNetworkStats(); //Updating network stats
long download2 = net.getBytesRecv();
long timestamp2 = net.getTimeStamp();
System.out.println("prova " + (download2 - download1)/(timestamp2 - timestamp1));
//Do the correct calculations
```

This solution is [here](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues/403) with oshi library. Thanks to YoshiEnVerde